# RxJs Subject resolve first emitted value as promise

Tags: rxjs

Is there a way to get a value that was emitted in a `Subject` or `BehviourSubject` by awaiting it with the `toPromise()` method?
I have tried using the `first()` operator, as well as the `take(1)` operator and that, did not seem to work as I have expected.
Something along the lines with the following would resemble my problem:

```
async function testSubjectToPromise() {
  const sub = new Subject<string>();
  sub.next("Hello");
  const response = sub.toPromise();
  console.log("Task added");
  const result = await response;
  console.log("Task completed");
}

testSubjectToPromise().finally(() => console.log("Done"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it in a more logical way:

```
const sub = new Subject<string>();
async function testSubjectToPromise() {
  console.log("Task added");
  const result = await sub.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  console.log("Task completed");
  return result;
}

testSubjectToPromise().then(x => console.log(x)).finally(() => console.log("Done"));
sub.next("Hello");
```

You have to use Subject outside of your function, because it triggers value emitter for the subject you used as the return value `toPromise()`. You're just waiting for outside event after declaring your promise.

If you want use existing value from your subject, just use ReplaySubject. Then your code would look like:

```
async function testSubjectToPromise() {
  const sub = new ReplaySubject<string>();
  console.log("Task added");
  sub.next("Hello");  
  const result = await sub.pipe(first()).toPromise();
  console.log("Task completed");
  return result;
}

testSubjectToPromise().then(x => console.log(x)).finally(() => console.log("Done"));
```